# Configure ProFTPD correctly on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, ftp, proftpd

-- My System Info

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Using SSL through LetsEncrypt module
- ProFTPD module Main
- domain is a WordPress

I know there're a lot subjects for this issue and I read dozens of documentations but unfortunately nothing of those solutions working with me,  I installed virtualmin correctly (I think) I'll write the commands that I run to make sure it's ok setup

-- Commands

`sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
-> This message A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available but the version installed currently has been locally modified appeared ONCE during setup and I chose Install the package maintainer's version
-> Reboot the system 
wget https://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh -O /root/virtualmin-install.sh`

Then I create the first virtual server for my main domain and sub domains and request LetsEncrypt certificates and all working very well.

-- My Issue with FTP, WordPress and FileZilla

1- I tried to login in FileZilla with Host: ftp@DOMAIN_NAME.com but I received the following messages...

```
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I made some searches and I see this command **modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp** in {https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/faq#toc-ftp-service-isnt-working-Llnjz8K8} so I run it and reboot the system but the same messages appear ..

2- In my main domain I cannot add new plugin or media file and FTP credentials box appear too (I think it's related).

Comment: Any Suggestion?